# Passing json data to template

Tags: python, json, web, flask

I'm new to flask & web dev.  I want to pass output of an algorithm to template so I can show it to user. But I'm doing something wrong and don't see any output in HTML other then empty bullet points.

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from image_processing import find_cross_v4
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def run_algorithms():
        return {'file_name': f.filename, 'set_min': 'hello world 1','rep_sec':'hello world 2'}

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
   f = request.files['file']
   f.save("image_processing/query.jpg")
   data = run_algorithms()
   #jsondata = jsonify(data)
   #data =json.loads(jsondata)
   return render_template('results.html',data=data)

@app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def test():
  try:
    f = request.files['file']
    f.save("image_processing/query.jpg")
  except KeyError:
    return jsonify({'error': 'File Missing'})
  result = run_algorithms(f)
  return jsonify(result)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.debug = True
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**results.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1 class="logo">Results</h1>

   <ul>
    {% for data in data %}
    <li>{{data.file_name}}</li>
    <li>{{data.set_min}}</li>
    <li>{{data.rep_sec}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

I hit '/test' from command line

```
curl --form file=@somefile.jpg http://0.0.0.0:5000/test
```

Got below as output.

> {
>        "file_name": "somefile.jpg", 
>        "rep_sec": "hello world 2", 
>        "set_min": "hello world 1"     }

Results when I try things via browser
[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you are converting `data` to JSON (assuming that's what `jsonify` does) then immediately converting it back.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I didn't know if I was passing right JSON so I played around with jsonify and load.json() but it didn't help

Comment: Well, programming by chance is rarely successful. You don't need JSON at all here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: This works for me: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1627/
Just var data = {{data|tojson|safe}}

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1 class="logo">Results</h1>

   <ul>
    {% for item in data %}
    <li>{{item.file_name}}</li>
    <li>{{item.set_min}}</li>
    <li>{{item.rep_sec}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>

 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed 'for' statement in HTML template and it worked!

Comment: That's because your `data` object is a dictionary; looping over the dictionary yields keys. None of the keys have a `file_name` attribute, or either of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
 result = find_cross_v4.image_processing(f)
```

You aren't doing anything with that `f` parameter, is it intended? Since strange things may be going on in there, test flask-related functionalities with a mock-function, i.e.:

```
def run_algorithms(f):
    return {'file_name': 'sample file name', 'set_min': 'minimum value','rep_sec': 'other placeholding data'}
```

If this outputs data as expected (which it should), then you've isolated the error in the image processing code (or, more likely, the returned value).

Comment: Good point. I was not able to pass image directly to image_processing function, so instead I saved image as 'query.jpg' and opened it inside image_processing function.

Comment: Then start by not passing any parameters to the `run_algorithms()` function, it's very misleading ;)

Comment: try with a mock-result in `run_algorithms` as I explain in the update

Answer (score 0):

Your run_algorithms method does not have any parameter but while returning a dictionary,

```
{'file_name': f.filename, ... }
```

You use a 'f' object to return the filename but it does not come from anywhere. So what you should do is, in the upload method :

```
data = run_algorithms(f) # call the method with f parameter.
```

and add this parameter to your run_algorithms method :

```
def run_algorithms(f):
    return {'file_name': f.filename, 'set_min': 'hello world 1','rep_sec':'hello world 2'}
```

I hope this helps.
Good Luck !